# OroCRM Enterprise Edition - version 5.1 Setup

Tags: php, git, composer-php, orocrm, postgresql-15

I am trying to evaluate OroCRM (OroCRM Enterprise Edition - version 5.1 - latest stable) in an on premise virtual machine. It seems there is no Virtualbox VM for OroCRM, only for OroCommerce. I then tried installing it according to the page https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/setup/get-source-files/#installation-get-files, but either with the composer or the git clone solution, the setup always fails on

```
Executing script cache:clear --env=prod [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear --env=prod returned with error code 1
!!
!!   // Clearing the cache for the prod environment with debug
!!   // false
!!
!!
!!  In AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php line 82:
!!
!!    An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT o0_.id AS id_0, o0_.parent_id
!!     AS sclr_1, o1_.code AS code_2 FROM oro_localization o0_ INNER JOIN oro_lan
!!    guage o1_ ON o0_.language_id = o1_.id':
!!
!!    SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation "oro_localization" doe
!!    s not exist
!!    LINE 1: ... o0_.parent_id AS sclr_1, o1_.code AS code_2 FROM oro_locali...
!!             `        `                                            ^
```

I manually created the oro_db_user with the corresponding password in the Postgresql 15 local service (before that it gave a connection error).
I think there might be something missing in the installation script? Since i get no more db connection errors and there are no tables created in postgres, i think it forget to run the migrations to create the necessary tables?
Any suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: Are you sure this problem is in any way related to git or Composer? If you haven't written any code on your own, you should report this as a bug to the maintainers of the software you are evaluating

Answer (score 0):

Issue is solved when installing version 5.1.5 instead of 5.1.0.
Downloaded from
https://github.com/oroinc/crm-application/releases/download/5.1.5/crm-application-5.1.5.zip